# Display dialog box in landscape

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone

Using Xna for a game on windows phone, and at the beginning I have a prompt for if the user wants to continue listening to music via `Microsoft.Xna.GamerServices.Guide.BeginShowMessageBox()`.

However, this prompt displays in portrait while my game runs in landscape, is there a setting I'm unable to find which would allow me to landscape my dialog box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DisplayOrientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.presentationparameters.displayorientation.aspx?queryresult=true) property.

```
GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.DisplayOrientation = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
```

Property cannot be set, before content is loaded and works on Windows Phones platfrom only (not on XBox and Windows).